# How to Parse HTML from Websites eg. to count Words in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In Java i have jsoup but i cant find anything similar for Angular to that.

With jsoup its pretty simple to do the task:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(SITE).get();
    String text = doc.body().text();
```

I've played around with HttpClient() but the code starts to grow and becomes too complex.

Any advices?

Comment: @bolov Angular is a whole framework, in some aspects greater than JQuery. It is advised not use JQuery with it, because it leads to DOM manipulation, which is "forbidden" in Angular.

Comment: As for the OP, Angular is a front-end framework, it can't process data from other websites. Consider that the scope of Angular is limited to the tab your application is opened in.

Comment: @trichetriche got it, thank you. Removed my comment